# Switching to Right-to-left in 13.10

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, hebrew, rtl

I can't seem to be able to switch to Right-to-Left which is critical for writing in Hebrew.

Any idea on what I can do to fix it?

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: Just tried hitting R Ctrl + R Shift Which used to do the trick in 13.04.

Comment: Plus I looked for a shortcut in the "keyboard" settings. Didn't find one for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. Fixed in 14.04.

Cheers